# A problem in solving a simple electronics circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electronics

In the circuit given below are 5V and -2V supplies connected in parallel to each other? 
Is input at upper terminal of op amp 3V?
If not 3 then what? please elaborate these three points. I am trying to learn electronics at home. When I tried to solve numericals I stuck here.
[image]

Comment: Is the gain of the op amp infinite?

Comment: You are wrong to think the input at the inverting terminal is 3 V. The resistors don't have equal weight - so you can't just sum the voltages.

Comment: @Floris are 5v and -2 volt supplies not connected in parallel to resistors?

Comment: To create this situation, you could put a 5V and 2V battery in series, with their common junction at ground, and that would give you the same circuit (the same voltages at the terminals of the input resistors). Then you see you just put 7 v across 14 k, giving you a 2 mA current. Which puts the inverting input node at 0 V.

Answer (score 1):

With the values given, it's pretty easy to see that the voltage at the inverting input of the opamp will be zero with no need for current from the output (in other words - 0 V output).

If you want to do this "properly", all the currents flowing into the opamp must equal all the currents flowing out. The inverting input is assumed to be at ground ("virtual ground") - this is approximately true for opamps with large gain, and exactly true for ideal opamps.

The current is then given simply from

$$I = \frac{V_1}{R_1}+\frac{V_2}{R_2} + \frac{V_3}{R_3} = 0\\
\Rightarrow\\
V_3 = -R_3\cdot\left(\frac{V_1}{R_1}+\frac{V_2}{R_2}\right)$$

Which is zero for the values given.